# Excel VBA Combobox OnExit Event

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have the code:

```
Private Sub TempCombo_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

But when i exit from TempCombo nothing happens?

What's wrong?

Obs: i need to do a validation when lost focus

Comment: Is the ComboBox on a worksheet or a userform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveX comboboxes don't have an Exit event. Go to the sheet's module and choose TempCombo from the left drop down and you'll get a list of events from the right drop down. I think the LostFocus event is what you'll want.